# Calculate the Average By Date

Tags: excel

In column A I have dates and in column B I have values.

How to calculate the average of values whose date have Month = 4 and Year = 2012?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like a good use for AverageIfs...

[image]

Comment: I need to consider regional effects more often. +1 for addressing regional issues.  I typically don't.  yeah I htought about B:B and A:A but then I had to move my average total to column C: and *sheash* that column c is rough.

Comment: 40999 may not be locale sensitive but it is date system sensitive (i.e. 40999 isn't the same date with 1904 date system).....it's also not very transparent. I would use unambiguous DATE function like DATE(2012,4,1) or perhaps better to have 1st of month in a cell like D2 and then use `=AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&D2,A:A,"<"&EOMONTH(D2,0)+1)`

Answer (score 1):

There are MANY ways to do this, but here's one way:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B4,--(MONTH(A1:A4)=4),--(YEAR(A1:A4)=2013))/SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(A1:A4)=4),--(YEAR(A1:A4)=2013))
```

Of course, change the row numbers to match your data range

Comment: Yes, that is a way ... But why the "--"? And when there is no date with that year or month I get a division by 0. I tried a few ways and I always get one problem or the other ...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, assuming that you want to follow method one, let's use 2010 as the year base (a non-leap year). This array formula will give you a result of 19th November:

```
=AVERAGE(DATE(2010,MONTH(A1:A7),DAY(A1:A7)))
```

When you type it into the formula bar you need to complete the entry with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER (not just the usual ENTER) so that Excel surrounds the formula with parentheses { }.
You then need to format the cell as a date, eg. dd mmm.

If there are blank cells in the range then the above formula would give an incorrect result so it would have to be adapted as follows (made more complicated):

```
=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A7),DATE(2010,MONTH(A1:A7),DAY(A1:A7))))
```

This is also an array formula.

Comment: I used the CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER approach to get the {} before. And it worked .. Similar to your first example. But why it is necessary to use the {}? What does it do exactly?

Comment: It's called ARRAY FORMULAS. For exemple: [http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx]

Comment: Doesn't this average the dates - surely the idea is to average the values if they fall in a specific month, e.g. `=AVERAGE(IF(MONTH(A1:A10)=4,IF(YEAR(A1:A10)=2012,B1:B10)))`